# De-animate Sticky Header

Tags: jquery, css, sticky

In this demo http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/StickyTableHeaders/index3.html , is there a way to have the bars with the fields at the top and the sides stay at an absolute position? So when the user scrolls either horizontal or vertical, instead of the bar floating up or down or left or right at the speed of the scroll, it stays locked in position while the table behind is scrolling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Miah said the transition property in CSS should be removed. I'm forcing it to none.

```
.sticky-wrap .sticky-thead,
.sticky-wrap .sticky-col,
.sticky-wrap .sticky-intersect {
    transition: none !important;
}
```

Also in `jquery.stickyheader.js`, `scroll` is called with a 15ms throttle.

**For left column**

```
$t.parent('.sticky-wrap').scroll($.throttle(15, function() {
```

change to...

```
$t.parent('.sticky-wrap').scroll($.throttle(0, function() {
```

**For top header**

```
.scroll($.throttle(15, repositionStickyHead));
```

change to...

```
.scroll($.throttle(0, repositionStickyHead));
```

...

**Complete Snippet**

```css
.sticky-wrap .sticky-thead,
.sticky-wrap .sticky-col,
.sticky-wrap .sticky-intersect {
  transition: none !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/StickyTableHeaders/css/normalize.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/StickyTableHeaders/css/demo.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/StickyTableHeaders/css/component.css" />

<div class="component">
    <table class="">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Population</th>
                <th>Alpha</th>
                <th>Beta</th>
                <th>Gamma</th>
                <th>Delta</th>
                <th>Epsilon</th>
                <th>Zeta</th>
                <th>Eta</th>
                <th>Theta</th>
                <th>Iota</th>
                <th>Kappa</th>
                <th>Lambda</th>
                <th>Mu</th>
                <th>Nu</th>
                <th>Xi</th>
                <th>Omicron</th>
                <th>Pi</th>
                <th>Rho</th>
                <th>Sigma</th>
                <th>Tau</th>
                <th>Upsilon</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>Sample #1</th>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>88</td>
                <td>8</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>67</td>
                <td>83</td>
                <td>81</td>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>91</td>
                <td>96</td>
                <td>13</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>95</td>
                <td>98</td>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>87</td>
                <td>70</td>
                <td>54</td>
                <td>72</td>
                <td>75</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Sample #2</th>
                <td>14</td>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>20</td>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>9</td>
                <td>68</td>
                <td>60</td>
                <td>73</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>29</td>
                <td>9</td>
                <td>49</td>
                <td>49</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>58</td>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>8</td>
                <td>24</td>
                <td>19</td>
                <td>65</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Sample #3</th>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>50</td>
                <td>89</td>
                <td>72</td>
                <td>99</td>
                <td>90</td>
                <td>24</td>
                <td>86</td>
                <td>95</td>
                <td>44</td>
                <td>32</td>
                <td>97</td>
                <td>18</td>
                <td>90</td>
                <td>81</td>
                <td>9</td>
                <td>38</td>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>85</td>
                <td>15</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Sample #4</th>
                <td>10</td>
                <td class="err">Parse error</td>
                <td>32</td>
                <td>45</td>
                <td>53</td>
                <td>29</td>
                <td>35</td>
                <td>35</td>
                <td>75</td>
                <td>9</td>
                <td>69</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>93</td>
                <td>42</td>
                <td>81</td>
                <td>85</td>
                <td>72</td>
                <td>70</td>
                <td>15</td>
                <td>38</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Sample #5</th>
                <td>85</td>
                <td>42</td>
                <td>71</td>
                <td>56</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>41</td>
                <td>87</td>
                <td>94</td>
                <td>99</td>
                <td>24</td>
                <td>20</td>
                <td>96</td>
                <td>62</td>
                <td>90</td>
                <td>13</td>
                <td>38</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>9</td>
                <td>6</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Sample #6</th>
                <td>18</td>
                <td>80</td>
                <td>85</td>
                <td>65</td>
                <td>9</td>
                <td>93</td>
                <td>93</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>49</td>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>45</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>93</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>80</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>60</td>
                <td>53</td>
                <td>81</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Sample #7</th>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>81</td>
                <td>46</td>
                <td>50</td>
                <td>71</td>
                <td>60</td>
                <td>8</td>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>87</td>
                <td>34</td>
                <td>35</td>
                <td>74</td>
                <td>34</td>
                <td>31</td>
                <td>97</td>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>40</td>
                <td>95</td>
                <td>92</td>
                <td>93</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Sample #8</th>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>88</td>
                <td>8</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>67</td>
                <td>83</td>
                <td>81</td>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>91</td>
                <td>96</td>
                <td>13</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>95</td>
                <td>98</td>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>87</td>
                <td>70</td>
                <td>54</td>
                <td>72</td>
                <td>75</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Sample #9</th>
                <td>14</td>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>20</td>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>9</td>
                <td>68</td>
                <td>60</td>
                <td>73</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>29</td>
                <td>9</td>
                <td>48</td>
                <td>44</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>58</td>
                <td>15</td>
                <td>8</td>
                <td>24</td>
                <td>19</td>
                <td>65</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-throttle-debounce/1.1/jquery.ba-throttle-debounce.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/shivammathur/a703480e7ecaab648c501946f0602922/raw/42e4058257ac5c22069392bdc4f6b2b3aaf26033/stickyheader.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In component.css remove the transition from this block of CSS:

```
.sticky-wrap .sticky-thead,
.sticky-wrap .sticky-col,
.sticky-wrap .sticky-intersect {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: all .125s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 50;
  width: auto; /* Prevent table from stretching to full size */
}
```

As seen here:

```
.sticky-wrap .sticky-thead,
.sticky-wrap .sticky-col,
.sticky-wrap .sticky-intersect {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 50;
  width: auto; /* Prevent table from stretching to full size */
}
```

Comment: taking that out helps, but if you look back at it, it still moves some when you scroll. I need it to not move at all

Comment: When you say it "moves some" could you be more specific. I only see some glitching when scrolling quickly up and down. Is that what you are seeing as well?

Comment: Yeah thats what I mean, I need it to not move at all. The transition takes out the ease in and ease out but doesn't fix the movement

Answer (score 0):

I think You should use this css code:

```
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
```

to this bar
I have add this code, and it is working i think.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work. Even though it is fixed, once you scroll, the bar pops out of the div so you see the entire bar. It needs to stay within the container.

Comment: try position: sticky please